# Android 4 software buttons in emulator?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Android 4 ICS is supposed to have virtual menu, home and back buttons at the bottom. I don't see this in the emulator. Do I have to do something to enable that?

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted, but you could definitely expand the question a bit more.  Could you post a link to a screenshot (since you can't post images directly yet)?  Also, please post a screenshot of your virtual device's config screen (the one you have in VD manager)

Comment: Why would someone downvote this? Anyway. Here is an image that shows the virtual software buttons for home, menu and back, at the bottom the screen. http://cdn.gottabemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/ICS-Android01.jpg. I don't see these buttons when I launch the Android emulator running ICS platform. I am using the emulator's back, home and menu buttons. But, ideally, I will like to use the software buttons.

Comment: It's entirely possible that the emulator doesn't support it yet.  The emulator is one of the areas that Android really needs to improve, and this might just be a shortcoming.  Sorry I wasn't able to answer your question, hopefully someone is able to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

today Google solve this problem, you need to update the emulator to the rev16 version and Android ics system image 2.

[Xavier Ducrohet post this on Google+ today.](https://plus.google.com/109385828142935151413/posts/FqJ5oT2xWjm)

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the AVD resolution to WXGA720. Read about it somewhere and it and now the AVD shows the nav buttons.